# How to convert large timespan value into (hours:minutes:seconds) in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, time-format

I have a column value as `2.23:48:50` (day.hour:minute:second) in reporting services field.

I tried to convert using below code:

> (Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value/60) + ":" + (Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value - ((Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value/60) *60) +  ":00

and

> Format(DateAdd("s", (TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value))), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")

but it didn't work.

I need to display it as `71:48:50`.

How can I do this in Reporting Services?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your requirements are quite difficult:

1. Split string into three components based on different delimiters
2. Convert various components to integers and apply arithmetic to these
3. Concatenate all the different components to get one adjusted string

Based on this the following expression will work:

```
=CInt(Left(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ".") - 1))
  * 24
  + CInt(Mid(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value
    , InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ".") + 1
    , InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ":") - InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ".") - 1))
  & ":" & Right(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value
      , Len(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value) - InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ":"))
```

[image]

[image]

This works for your one example but you might need to adjust slightly for your larger dataset.

You could also simplify the expression by adding a set of calculated fields for smaller expressions like `Left(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, InStr(Fields!hrs_apprvd.Value, ".") - 1)` and then reference the calculated field in the table expression.

You can see the expression gets complicated very quickly - applying the transformation out of SSRS would also be worth investigating.